# How to remove part of a path from another path?

Tags: c#

I have two file paths like this:

```
var path1 = "c:\dir\anotherdir";
var path2 = "c:\dir\anotherdir\yetanotherdir\dirception\file.zip";
var result = path2 - path1; //Wanted result: yetanotherdir\dirception\file.zip
```

What I need to do, is to take the path1 and "remove" it from the path2.

Now the easiest solution would be to simply use substr, or something, and simply cut out the path1 from the path2 in a "text" way. But I would rather used some actual inbuilt functions in c#, intended for working with paths, to handle this.

I tried this:

```
var result = (new Uri(path1)).MakeRelativeUri(path2);
```

Expected result: yetanotherdir\dirception\file.zip

Actual result: anotherdir\yetanotherdir\dirception\file.zip

What is the best way to achieve my goal then?

Comment: Are the both pathes is actually strings? Is so you can just use string.Replace method.

Comment: Yes they are strings, but like i said i would rather not use simple text replacement, but rather some inbuild functions for handling paths for higher reliability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Path.GetFullPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath(v=vs.100).aspx), `String.StartsWith` and `String.Substring` should be reliable enough:

```
string path1 = @"c:\dir\anotherdir";
string path2 = @"c:\dir\anotherdir\yetanotherdir\dirception\file.zip";
string fullPath1 = Path.GetFullPath(path1);
string fullPath2 = Path.GetFullPath(path2);
if (fullPath2.StartsWith(fullPath1, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    string result = fullPath2.Substring(fullPath1.Length).TrimStart(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
    // yetanotherdir\dirception\file.zip
}
```

Comment: TrimStart ...yummmm ... :)

Comment: @Noctis: what's wrong with it? It's a reliable way to remove a directory-separator-char from the start of a path if it exists. I don't know why OP needs to remove it, but that's another question. He' free to skip the `TrimStart`, i just wanted to give him the desired result.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it, on the contrary :) The only thing I would have done different, is probably break the `.TrimStart` to the next line, aligned with the `.Substring`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just replace it out

```
var result = path2.Replace(path1+"/","");
```

Comment: this would leave an extra \

Comment: @Sayse what?? It's an empty string

Comment: `var path2 = "c:\dir\anotherdir\..` (not my dv btw)

Answer (score 0):

```
var path1 = @"c:\dir\anotherdir";
var path2 = @"c:\dir\anotherdir\yetanotherdir\dirception\file.zip";
var path3 = path2.Replace(path1,""); // Will hold : \yetanotherdir\dirception\file.zip
```

You can remove the first `\` if you want. 
But out of curiosity, why wouldn't you want the prefix of the path?

Comment: Fails for example if `path1` is `@"c:\dir\Anotherdir\"`, not to mention if `path1` is a relative path which occurs multiple times in `path2`.

Comment: 1. again, for his example, should work, If he has Upper and Lower case directories, they are not actually the same though. About 2. I doubt it'll happen if he has a `c:\` in the beginning, but fair enough.

Comment: Try to create a directory `Test` and another in the same folder with the name `test`. Acc. 2. relative paths never start with the root, that makes them relative.

Answer (score 0):

If you add an extra path separator char on the end of `path1` so it becomes:

```
var path1 = "c:\dir\anotherdir\";
```

Then the following should work:

```
var result = (new Uri(path1)).MakeRelativeUri(new Uri(path2));
```